# Is this a PHP / MYSQL mistake or is it a database bug?

Tags: php, mysql

I've only recently started php again, this is supposed to add another game to a chess game database and it's supposed to add all squares as empty, the squares in the database are saved as i0,i1..i63, turno is true when it's white's turn, otherwise false, and the primary key is not metioned here as it's auto increment.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","pierostesting","");
mysql_select_db("my_pierostesting");
$query = "INSERT INTO board(";
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
    $query.="i$i,";
}
$query.="turno) VALUES(";
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
    $query.="'empty',";}$query.="1)";
echo $query;
if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'nailed it';
}?>
```

Comment: On a side note: you shouldn't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and will be removed in PHP7 end of this year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Also please tell us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE board` and the output of `echo $query` before sending it to the My-SQL server

Comment: It was a problem with my database, thank you all.

Comment: What was the problem with your database? If you explain then it would be useful for other users who may get this same problem.

Comment: I simply didn't add i63 as a field and tried to save in it.

Answer (score 3):

Unaccepted `}` closing in your code it would be

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","pierostesting","");
mysql_select_db("my_pierostesting");
$query = "INSERT INTO board(";
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
    $query.="i$i,";
}
$query.="turno) VALUES(";
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
    $query.="'empty',";

}
    $query.="1)";


echo $query;
if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'nailed it';
}?>
```

And the output of this code is correct query as you write

Comment: Oh no that's not there in my main code, I added it wrongly when I posted. Edited and thank you.

Comment: So it's a problem with my database? Perfect, Diving right into phpmyadmin.

Comment: yes now this code is without any syntax mistake